# Lombok with IntelliJ problem: Lombok Dependency is possibly outdated

Tags: lombok, intellij-lombok-plugin

Here is error in IntelliJ.

Project "toy-api" and Module "toy-api" seem to have outdated lombok dependency added. Configured version "1.18.10", but there is at least version "1.18.18" already released

Does it mean I should update lombok version later than 1.18.18?
If it is true, could I use jdk 1.8 with lombok 1.18.18?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer: It is bug of IntelliJ.
For fixing it, you should upgrade.

Here is answer mail that I received.
[image]

After I upgraded to 2021.3.3, the error is not showed anymore.
But I think it is not best way because I still can't choose lombok version.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).